# Incorporating time series into a mixed effects model in R (using lme4)

Tags: r, time-series, lme4, mixed-models

I've had a search for similar questions and come up short so apologies if there are related questions that I've missed.

I'm looking at the amount of time spent on feeders (dependent variable) across various conditions with each subject visiting feeders 30 times.

Subjects are exposed to feeders of one type which will have a different combination of being scented/unscented, having visual patterns/being blank, and having these visual or scented patterns presented in one of two spatial arrangements.

So far my model is:

```
mod<-lmer(timeonfeeder ~ scent_yes_no + visual_yes_no + 
    pattern_one_or_two + (1|subject), data=data)
```

How can I incorporate the visit numbers into the model to see if these factors have an effect on the time spent on the feeders over time?

Comment: would you have an example of the data?

Comment: if you assume constant change across time (visit numbers) you just add it as additional level one predictor. if you assume varying change across subjects, you can additionally specify a random coefficient for the time variable. But let me ask: If you are interested in questions of timing (amount of time spend), shouldn't you rather do a duration analysis (aka event history analysis)?

Comment: @MathieuB here's how the data is put together
![post image](http://postimg.org/image/h85spau99/)
the data set is pretty huge so it would be difficult to show you the data of even just one subject.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have a variety of choices (this question might be marginally better for [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)).

- as @Dominix suggests, you can allow for a linear increase or decrease in time on feeder over time.  It probably makes sense to allow this change to vary across birds:

  ```
  timeonfeeder ~ time + ... + (time|subject)
  ```
- you *could* allow for an arbitrary pattern of change over time (i.e. not just linear):

  ```
  timeonfeeder ~ factor(time) + ... + (1|subject)
  ```

  this probably doesn't make sense in your case, because you have a large number of observations, so it would require many parameters (it would be more sensible if you had, say, 3 time points per individual)
- you could allow for a more complex pattern of change over time via an *additive* model, i.e. modeling change over time with a cubic spline. For example:

  ```
  library(mgcv)
  gamm(timeonfeeder ~ s(time) + ... , random = ~1|subject
  ```

  (1) this assumes the temporal pattern is the same across subjects; (2) because `gamm()` uses `lme` rather than `lmer` under the hood you have to specify the random effect as a separate argument.  (You could also use the `gamm4` package, which uses `lmer` under the hood.)
- You might want to allow for temporal autocorrelation.  For example,

  ```
  lme(timeonfeeder ~ time + ... ,
      random = ~ time|subject,
      correlation = corAR1(form= ~time|subject) , ...)
  ```

Comment: almost, but `(1|subject)` is redundant; `(visit_no|subject)` is equivalent to `(1+visit_no|subject)`, i.e. includes variation in both the slope and the intercept across subjects

Comment: Thanks all for taking the time to answer. I think as Dominix and Ben suggested my best option is to allow for a linear increase or decrease in time on feeder over time. Just to clarify if this is the case would I then change my model to...     
mod<-lmer(timeonfeeder ~ visit_no + scent_yes_no + visual_yes_no + 
    pattern_one_or_two + (1|subject) + (visit_no|subject), data=data). Forgive me if this isn't correct i'm fairly new to both r and mixed models (and commenting on Stack Overflow). Confusion abounds!

Comment: Brilliant thank you very much. Sorry about the terrible formatting.

Comment: if the question solved your problem, you are encouraged to click the check mark to accept it ...